# Migrating to Arrow function from Normal function JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hermione

In my project, I don't wanna use construction `function () {}`, instead of that I wanna use `() => {}` or `() => ()`. Code below. In first example I can see `this`, in second case `this` undefined. So I wonder, Is it possible way to make `() => {}` see `this`? I tried to use `() => {}.bind(this)` did not work and `({ context: this }) => {}` did not work either.

```js
// Example 1
describe('Currency converter', () => {
  it('should be shown on the page', function () {
    console.log(this); // { bla: ..., blabla: ... }
    return this.browser
      .url('/')
      .keys(['currence', '\uE007'])
      .isExisting('.converter-form')
      .then((exists) => {
        assert.ok(exists, 'currence did not show');
      });
  });
});

// Example 2
describe('Currency converter', () => {
  it('should be shown on the page', () => {
    console.log(this) // undefinded
    return this.browser
      .url('/')
      .keys(['currence', '\uE007'])
      .isExisting('.converter-form')
      .then((exists) => {
        assert.ok(exists, 'currence did not show');
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: what testing framework is this?

Comment: @DanielA.White, hermione

Comment: You are sending the `window` all the way down, you have to use `function` if you want to create a `this `reference. Since you are probably using `'use strict'` then `this` on `window` is `undefined`

Comment: hermione might be using `.call` or `.apply` and arrow functions neuter the context passed. ie. `() => { ... }` is the same as `(function() { ... }).bind(this)`

Comment: if you using fat arrow it should save you the need of using ".bind()"

Comment: @happyZZR1400 i'm guessing its something hermione is passing

Comment: i dont see any need of using this in the tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! Arrow functions don't have a their own value for `this`, even if you try to bind them. You have to use the long form.